# Is there anyway of getting javascript code injected in an iframe to execute without removing and reappending the script tag containing it?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-manipulation

*Context:*

I am building a live HTML,CSS & Javascript editor.
It can be accessed [here](http://experiments.muditameta.com/qckmeddler/).

The source can be accessed [here](https://github.com/zeusdeux/qckMeddler).

*Question:*

Is it possible to run javascript code injected into an iframe without repeated removal and addition of <script> tag containing the code from and to the DOM tree? Since DOM manipulation is a costly affair, I want to try and eliminate multiple DOM manipulations.
Instead I want to be able to just change the *textContent* of the <script> tag and have it run the new code that I've inserted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind using the *evil* [**`eval`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), you can re-evaluate most JavaScript in the iframe's window, for example

```
function someFunction(){                                // any function
    console.log(document.body.children);
}

someFunction();                                         // see normal output

var ifrm  = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0], // your iframe
    iwind = ifrm.contentWindow;                         // the iframe's window

iwind.eval( someFunction.toString() );                  // re-evaluate function with eval from iframe
iwind.someFunction();                                   // see new output - output is in iframe's context
```

compare against

```
iwind.someFunction = someFunction;                      // set variable
iwind.someFunction();                                   // same as calling someFunction() from parent
```

It should work for most valid JavaScript (take into account scope), but be aware that [using `eval` can be bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Yes you can use this with `iwind.eval( myScript.textContent );` too, but be aware that unless you set things you don't want any more to `null` or `undefined`, they will exist as long as the `iframe` is on the same page. This applies to removing & appending a new `<script>`, too.

Comment: is there a workaround for that? any garbage collection strategies that clean up after a `<script>` tag removal?

Comment: It's not that they don't get GC'd for no reason - when script from a `<script>` is evaluated, it is done in the context of the _Window_ and therefore any variables set or functions defined exist as long as it does. You could do a comparison of `Object.keys(window)` or `for(var key in window)` before and after and `delete` new properties, but you can't easily tell if an existing one has been modified.

Comment: Ok this is a long shot and arises from the fact that I cant seem to find any good documents on the way browsers interpret javascript, but :

what if i store the reference to the `iframe` `contentWindow` in a var in the parent window, then set the `iframe` `contentWindow` to null (to probably cause a GC sweep) and then set it back using the parent window `var` and use it after the gc sweep?
I am assuming that when i set the `contentWindow` of the `iframe` to null, it causes the GC to do a sweep.

Thanks for the speedy replies! :)

Comment: `node.contentWindow = null; node.contentWindow === null; // false`. Even if you could set it to `null`, it is an object so the variable in the parent window is _ByRef_ and it's properties would change with changes to those on `node.contentWindow`. Afaik the only way to destroy and recreate a Window object is to reload the page, hence my suggestion to compare `Object.keys(window)`.

Comment: that clears it all up. totally overlooked the reference aspect for some reason. Thanks!